# Keep getting a TypeError when referencing another function with module.exports

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, module

I am trying to get handlebars to re-render the page after a new item (parked vehicle) is added to the database.  i know it would be better to do this with a front end framework, but for now I am using jQuery.

The error message I keep getting:

> ui.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: index.getVehicles is not a function

My index.js file:

```
const app = require('./apiurl.js');
const events = require('./events.js');
const ui = require('./ui.js');


const displayVehicles = function(vehicles){
  const display = require('./vehicles.handlebars');
  $('.content').empty().append(display({ vehicles }));
  events.addHandlers();
};

const getVehicles = function(failure) {
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: app.api + '/vehicles/',
  }).done(function(data){
      displayVehicles(data.vehicles);
    })
    .fail(failure);
};

$(() => {
  getVehicles(ui.failure());
});


module.exports = {
  getVehicles,
  displayVehicles
};
```

The AJAX that is called when the button to submit a new item is clicked.  'ui.addVehicleSuccess' is passed in as the 'success' parameter.

```
const addVehicle = (success, failure, data) => {
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: app.api + '/vehicles/',
    dataType: 'json',
    dataProcessing: false,
    data
  }).done(success)
    .fail(failure);
};
```

[EDIT - added full ui file, to show that I am requiring index.js there] My ui.js file:

```
const index = require('./index.js');


const success = (data) => {
  console.log(data);
};

const failure = (error) => {
  console.log(error);
};

const addVehicleSuccess = (data) => {
  console.log(data);
  index.getVehicles();
};


module.exports = {
  failure,
  success,
  addVehicleSuccess
};
```

I have no idea why it's saying index.getVehicles is not a function.  It works on page load, just not on reload when adding an item.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are requiring ui.js from index.js but trying to execute a function declared on index.js from ui.js which isn't declared on that scope

Comment: Please see my edit - I do require index.js in the ui.js file.

Comment: You might want to re design your code, now you have a circular dependancy, index.js and ui.js are mutually required.

Comment: I just want to re-run the handlebars render when a new item is added - where is the best place to put that while remaining DRY?

Comment: The simplest would be to make ui.js not depend on index.js, or vice versa

Comment: I get the same error message when I make index.js not depend on ui.js